# Deciphering a wget command

Tags: linux, cron, wget

I'm trying to set up a cron job and I've been supplied the following command: `wget -0 - -t 1` but I can't quite figure it out using this resource: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/wget.htm.

What does the `-0 - -t 1` mean? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it is "-0" (zero), not "-O" ('O' letter) ?

Answer (score 1):

According to both the wget manual you linked (and my own `man wget` on a Ubuntu machine) there is no `-0` option. Maybe it's supposed to be a captial letter O?

That would make sense since `-O` is used to specify output filename.

> -O file:
>   The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion.

`-t` stands for the number of retries.

Comment: That was where I was getting stuck: there didn't appear to be an entry for 0 (zero. I will try with O (letter)